# Tewr.Blazor.FileReader - File Name

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am currently using the following to upload the files selected.  However, I would like to use the file name of the local file for the server file name.  I have not been able to discover how to recover that name.

public async Task ReadFile()
{

```
    foreach (var file in await fileReaderService.CreateReference(inputTypeFileElement).EnumerateFilesAsync())
    {
        
        // Read into buffer and act (uses less memory)
        await using (Stream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            buffer = new Byte[stream.Length];
            // Do (async) stuff with stream...
            await stream.ReadAsync(buffer);
        }

        // Read file fully into memory and act
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = await file.CreateMemoryStreamAsync(4096))
        {
            // Sync calls are ok once file is in memory
            memoryStream.Read(buffer);
            docManager.WriteImageToFile(memoryStream, upLoadFileName, Season);
        }
    }

}
```

How can I get the local file name in code?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the `FileInfo` using the following code inside your foreach-loop:

```cs
IFileInfo fileInfo = await file.ReadFileInfoAsync();
string fileName = fileInfo.Name;
string contentType = fileInfo.Type;
```